# How can i find my current location if i am indoor? ANDROID

Tags: android

I want to find my current location if GPS is not avaible and there is no wireless?
I think i need to do some calculation or there is some codes that it can do it for me.?

Thx.

I wrote like that code but it can not find current location when i am indoor.

```
package com.anil.bestlocation;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.LocationProvider;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class showBestLocation extends Activity implements LocationListener{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private static final String[] S = { "Out of Service", 
                                        "Temporarily Out of Service", 
                                        "Available" };
    private TextView output;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String bestProvider;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLoc);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //list all providers
        List<String> providers = locationManager.getAllProviders();
        for(String provider : providers){
            printProvider(provider);
        }

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        output.append("\n\nBEST PROVIDER:\n");
        printProvider(bestProvider);

        output.append("Location.. (initialized with the last known location):");
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
        printLocation(location);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 20000, 1, this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        printLocation(location);

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        output.append("\n\nSProvider Disabled: " + provider);

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        output.append("\n\nProvider Enabled: " + provider);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        output.append("\n\nProvider Status Changed: " + provider + 
                      ", Status= " + S[status]);

    }

    private void printProvider(String provider){
        LocationProvider info = locationManager.getProvider(provider);
        output.append(info.toString() + "\n\n");
    }

    private void printLocation(Location location){
        if(location == null){
            output.append("\nLocation UNKNOWN\n\n");
        }
        else{
            output.append("\n\nLatitude: " + location.getLatitude() + "\nLongitude: " + location.getLongitude());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: "Do some calculations" over *what*, exactly?

Comment: I really don't know excatly but i can say like that, sometimes GPS is not avaible for finding location, and if it is not avaible i am getting location on wi-fi but if there is no wi-fi, what can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indoors you can use the NetworkProvider to get location. This method uses a combination of mobile cell tower information and nearby wifi base station information to approximate your location.

The way it does this is by scanning the area for wifi base stations and collecting the mobile operator's cell tower information from nearby cell towers. **It then sends all this data to a server and asks the server to estimate your location.**

If you have no Internet access (ie: no wifi connection and no mobile data connection) then you will not get any location information. There isn't anything you can do about this. That's just the way it works.

Comment: Based on the code you've posted I don't see where you are using the NetworkProvider for location updates. You request and save `bestProvider` using no criteria. Which provider are you getting as best provider? If you want to get both GPS locations and network locations, you will need to call `requestLocationUpdates()` twice, once for each provider.

Comment: i called requestLocationUpdates() in onResume method

Comment: Yes, I saw that. But when you call requestLocationUpdates() you must specify the provider that you want the updates to come from. You have passed `bestProvider` as the first parameter in this method call. What is the value of the String `bestProvider` when you make this call? I'm assuming that it is the GPS provider. This means that you will only get location updates from the GPS provider. You will never get any location updates from the network provider.

Comment: Try this: in `onResume()` replace `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 20000, 1, this);
` with these 2 lines: `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 20000, 1, this); locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 20000, 1, this);`

Comment: You are absolutely right. So i want to find how can get any location updates from the network provider.

Comment: Did you see my previous comment?

Comment: Ok, now i want to ask one question, this code will work indoor yes?

Comment: It should work indoors, yes, if you have an Internet connection so that the location information can be sent to the server.

Comment: And if there is no wi-fi and no mobile data connection this will not work, yes?

Comment: Like I said, if you have no wifi connection and no mobile data connection you can't get a (reliable) network location. So, no. It won't work without Internet.

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html

More Specifically:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html#BestPerformance

Answer (score 0):

You will need some sort of input to retrieve the location. Your calculations will have to be based on something. Depending on your phones hardware, you could try and use bluetooth, NFC or try and detects some frequency that is emitted by a transmitter (That will have to be placed at the location). I hope this helps you.